# Выравнивание в Android

Tags: xml, java, android, eclipse

Имею **RelativeLayout**, Хочу поставить кнопку в произвольном месте, но меня всегда автоматически сдвигает. Как убрать авто-выравнивание?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Забудьте  про билдер и делфи  ─ при использовании RelativeLayout важно понимать относительно чего вы выравниваете, в любом случае как бы не был хорош графический редактор         руками править придется [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: Я читал что там все построено на выравнивании по соседям, но была мысль что может можно это убрать, эх. например у меня есть текст Описание: и сразу под ним хочу выводить текст, но увы, без margin-a прописанного вручную не обойтись.

Comment: плохо читали layout_below и будет счастье ) очень гибкие настройки - выше, ниже, правее, левее и много всего другого

Comment: в Relative Layout можно выравнивать как по родителю так и по другому элементу, скажем можно выравнить правую сторону элемента "A" по левой стороне элемента "B"